# elasticsearch kills cpu even after uninstall

Tags: elasticsearch

I uninstalled elasticsearch thinking it was the cause to a problem with my ruby app, turns out it wasn't. I reinstalled the version of elasticsearch I needed (1.1.1), however now it is destroying my cpu speed. It varies from 170-300% on my macbook 2013 (16 gb ram, 500 gb ssd, i7).

I ran brew uninstall elasticsearch again, but nothing changes. Elasticsearch is still being run somehow.

Is there a way to do a clean sweep of elasticsearch? since there are apparently multiple instances installed on my computer?

I know that it is elasticsearch because of the report from a spindump on the java process in the activity monitor. In addition the java process took up less than %1 before I had uninstalled ES last week.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe just kill the process? Did you try that already?

Comment: @JettroCoenradie I did. comes back immediately with a new process number.

Comment: And you are running this on a Mac? Sorry, but I do not know of an option in this area. You should be able to find out what files are in use by the process. Maybe you can find the location of the elastic search installation